# Instantiation of a class that uses IOption

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

In ASP.NET Core 2.1 I have a class to send e-mail that uses IOptions interface as shown bellow:

```
public class Email
{
    private readonly ManuelaIbiEmail manuelaIbiEmail;

    public Email(IOptions<ManuelaIbiEmail> manuelaIbiEmail)
    {
        this.manuelaIbiEmail.Username = manuelaIbiEmail.Value.Username;
        this.manuelaIbiEmail.Password = manuelaIbiEmail.Value.Password;
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(Contato contato)
    {
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net",
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = true,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(manuelaIbiEmail.Username, manuelaIbiEmail.Password)
        };

        using (var message = new MailMessage(contato.Email, "manuelaibi66@gmail.com")
        {
            Subject = "Email de Manuela Ibi Nutrição Integrada",
            Body = $"{contato.Comentario}\nTelefone: {contato.Telefone}"
        })
        {
            await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message);
        }
    }
}
```

This class has to be instantiated in the controller with a line like "var whatever = new Email(???);" in order that the SendAsync method can be called.

But the big picture here is that I'm lost in this initialization. I just don't know what to call in "Email(*something*)".

Just, giving a little more information in case is needed:

The system should read the username, password from Secrets and thus I have the following line in Startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<ManuelaIbiEmail>(Configuration.GetSection("ManuelaIbiEmail"));
```

The ManuelaIbiEmail is a very simple POCO class:

```
public class ManuelaIbiEmail
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The controller looks like:

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    private readonly ManuelaIbiEmail manuelaIbiEmail;

    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View(new Contato());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ContactAsync(Contato contato)
    {
        var email = new Email();
        email.SendAsync(contato);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

If anyone can be kind enough to tell me what I am missing, I'd appreciate.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you are calling `new Email(...)` then you are doing DI wrong, inject that class as well as the `IOptions`

Comment: Don't inject `IOptions<ManuelaIbiEmail>` into `Email`. Instead, inject `ManuelaIbiEmail` directly into `Email`, as described [here](https://simpleinjector.org/aspnetcore#working-with-ioptions-t).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of dependency injection is to *not do that*.

You can inject it either in the method via attributes:

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View(new Contato());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ContactAsync(Contato contato, [FromServices]Email email)
    {
        email.SendAsync(contato);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Or through constructor injection:

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    private readonly EMail email;

    public ContactController(Email email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View(new Contato());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ContactAsync(Contato contato)
    {
        email.SendAsync(contato);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you do not want to tightly couple your controller to implementation concerns by manually initializing the `Email` as *classes should depend on abstractions and not concretions*.

Abstract the email class

```
public interface IEmail {
    Task SendAsync(Contato contato);
}

public class Email: IEmail {
    //...omitted for brevity
}
```

and you could inject it into the controller via constructor injection

```
public class ContactController : Controller {
    private readonly IEmail email;

    public ContactController(IEmail email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public IActionResult Contact() {
        return View(new Contato());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ContactAsync(Contato contato) {        
        await email.SendAsync(contato);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Once configured correctly

```
services.AddTransient<IEmail, Email>();
```

the container will resolve all dependencies while creating the object graph for injection.

Answer (score 1):

Just inject `Email` via the constructor:

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    public ContactController(Email email)
    {
        Email = email;
    }

    public Email Email { get; }

    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        return View(new Contato());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ContactAsync(Contato contato)
    {
        Email.SendAsync(contato);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: On top of that, don't inject `IOptions<ManuelaIbiEmail>` into `Email`. Instead, inject `ManuelaIbiEmail` directly into `Email`.

Answer (score -1):

My proposition :

[Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.options.create?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Options_Options_Create__1___0_) a `IOption` instance and init your class Email with this instance

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

var mail = new ManuelaIbiEmail() { Username= "", Password="" };
IOptions<ManuelaIbiEmail> options = Options.Create(mail);
var email = new Email(options);
```

Comment: If one of my devs showed me this code, I'd give them a slap on the wrist and make them go do it properly (like the other answers)

Comment: This should probably not be in production code. However, it might be really helpful for unit testing scenarios. If you give your answer that spin, people will probably not downvote it. It's valid info, it's just not what one should normally do.

Comment: I tried to give a correct information. Although it likes a trick and dirty solution, it can still help to resolve this question and be helpful in a certain aspect.  But you can downvote as you want, everyone has an opinion. My answer has his value and I don't delete it :)

Comment: @nvoigt But the question doesn't ask for unit testing help, so even with that spin I wouldn't find this answer to be "good"